# How to make a Floating Context Menu for multiple views in a FrameLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am adding into a `FrameLayout` the views in this way

```
frameLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    View view = adapter.getView(i, null, frameLayout);
                    frameLayout.addView(view);
                    registerForContextMenu(view);
                }
            }
        });
```

And in `onCreateContextMenu` i save the view selected in a variable

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_page_lesson_menu, menu);
        selectedView = v; // Saved view
    }
```

But in `onContextItemSelected` when i try to access it, it is `null`

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.remove:
                db.delete(selectedView.getID()); // Error selectedView is null
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

All this code is in the same Fragment class.

```
public class MyFragment {

    private View selectedView;

    // Code...

}
```

Additional information.

- `selectedView` should not be null because onContextItemSelected is
  called after onCreateContextMenu, right?
- if `selectedView` is declared `static` there isn't a `NullPointerException`
  and everything is fine.
- `frameLayout` just in `onContextItemSelected` result empty (frameLayout.getChildCount()) when it is
  not

Comment: It's not clear why you'd want to stack a bunch of `View`s from an `Adapter` in a `FrameLayout`, but it would seem that you have multiple instances of that `Fragment` active, intentionally or not. The `onContextItemSelected()` method is called for each active `Fragment`, until one returns `true` to indicate that the selection has been handled. If you're only supposed to have one `MyFragment` instance running at a time, then you should find out where the others are coming from. Otherwise, it'll take some tedious work to make sure that the context menu is meant for a given instance and `View`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much for the comment. I did use a `FrameLayout ` because i'm doing a calendar and with `ListView` i couldn't position Views well (`view.setY` didn't work). Yes there are multiple instance of the `Fragment `becouse i'm using a `ViewPager`. So that is the problem. What about put the `selectedView` `static` as a solution?

Comment: Yeah, that'd probably work, mostly, but it's kinda hacky, and static `View` references are a general no-no. Probably a better, but not-too-terribly-tedious, way would be to do a null check on `selectedView` first in `onContextItemSelected()` – returning `false` if it is null – and setting `selectedView = null;` in `onContextMenuClosed()`. With that, and your setting `selectedView = v;` in `onCreateContextMenu()`, only the current `Fragment` should have a non-null `selectedView`.

Comment: @MikeM. It works, thanks. It is what i was looking for

Comment: Whoops, I was mistaken in my suggestion. I noticed that you overrode `onOptionsMenuClosed()` instead of `onContextMenuClosed()`, as I had suggested. I just realized that `Fragment` doesn't have the `onContextMenuClosed()` method, so obviously you couldn't do that, and there's still a subtle bug in your code. Get rid of the `onOptionsMenuClosed()` method altogether, and move `selectedView = null;` to `onContextItemSelected()`, after it's used. You really should do it in both the `case` and `default`, or refactor that to have only one `return` statement at the end, and do it right before that.

Answer (score 0):

From Mike M. comment

The problem was that there were multiple instances of MyFragment since it is in a ViewPager. (The previous code works without ViewPager)

The working code now is:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_page_lesson_menu, menu);
        selectedView = v;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(selectedView == null){
            return false;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.remove) {
            db.deleteLesson(selectedView.getId());
        }
        selectedView = null;
        return true;
    }
```